# Updating value based on two other values with the use of mapping table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables; one lookup table which will rarely be updated, and one data table which will be updated frequently.

Lookup table looks like this, where the combination of Code1 and Code2 is unique for each row.

```
Code1 | Code2 | Classification
------------------------------
AB    | CD    | Class1
XX    | YY    | Class2
```

Data table looks like this;

```
SomeData | Code1 | Code2 | Classification
------------------------------
foo      |AB     | CD    | 
bar      |XX     | YY    |
```

I need to dynamically update the data table with the Classification corresponding to the unique combination of Code1 and Code2 in the lookup table.

What would be the simplest / most elegant way of achieving this?

Comment: Why?  Just use `JOIN` to get the values when you need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update 2 table like this

```
UPDATE table1, table2
SET table2.Classification = table1.Classification
WHERE table1.Code2 = table2.Code2 AND table1.Code1 = table2.Code1;
```

Comment: Needed to make a slight mod to make this work in t-sql;
begin tran
UPDATE table1
SET table2.Classification = table1.Classification
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.Code2 = table2.Code2 AND table1.Code1 = table2.Code1
commit tran

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to join the 2 tables like this :

```
Select b.SomeData, b.Code1, b.Code2, a.Classification
FROM
Lookup_table a
left join
Data_table b
on (a.Code1 = b.Code1 and a.Code2 = b.Code2)
```

So your update becomes :

```
Update b
Set b.Classification = a.Classification 
FROM 
Data_table b
Right join
Lookup_table a
on (a.Code1 = b.Code1 and a.Code2 = b.Code2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just create view with this code and get whenver you want

```
select t2.somedata,t1.Code1,t1.Code2,t1.Classification from lookup_table as t1 
left join data_table as t2 on t1.code1=t2.code1 and t1.code2=t2.code2
```

If you still need to update, use this

```
update t2
set
t2.Classification=t2.Classification
 from lookup_table as t1 
inner join data_table as t2 on t1.code1=t2.code1 and t1.code2=t2.code2
```